# PyOpenCL kernel not being applied to entire array

Tags: python-3.x, opencl, pyopencl

I wanted to get a feel for Elementwise demo that comes with PyOpenCL and decided to try this out:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as cl_array
import numpy
from pyopencl.elementwise import ElementwiseKernel

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

n = 6

a_gpu = cl.array.to_device(queue,
numpy.arange(1, n, dtype=int))

update_a = ElementwiseKernel(ctx,
"int *a",
"a[i] = 2*a[i]",
"update_a")

print(a_gpu.get())
update_a(a_gpu)
print(a_gpu.get())
```

Which I expected to print out

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[2 4 6 8 10]
```

but I'm instead getting

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[2 4 6 4 5] .
```

Furthermore, when I try to store the "i" value into the array to see what's going on, I get some really weird values. They are all over the place and some are even negative.

I have been trying to make sense of this for a while now but can't. Can somebody please explain why this is happening? thanks.

Related info: PyOpenCL Version: 2018.2.1, Python Version: 3.6.5, OS: macOS 10.14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug lies in the vagueness of the typing of the numpy array, which has led to inconsistent strides along elements of the array on the CPU vs CL-device sides

Specifying `dtype=int` is ambiguous, and assumes 8-byte `np.int64` or `long` elements. 
The matching type on the CL-device side should be `long *a_in` for `np.int64`.

If you want to stick with 4-byte integers, specify `dtype=np.int32` on the CPU side and `int *a_in` on the CL-device side.

Takeaway: *Always specify your numpy array types with clarity, e.g., `dtype=np.int64`.* And check for a precise match on the CL-device side.